# How do holographic mirrors work?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, reflection, hologram

I found this hologram on a book.

Apart from the usual rainbow colors,  it sported a ***convex mirror effect*** on it.

[image: pic1]

**Here,  you can see my phone's reflection in the tiny circles.**

It would be interesting to know how they make ***mirror like reflections*** on a *plane flat holographic sticker?*

***Maybe we could  use these holographic mirrors as a substitute for the ordinary spherical mirrors*** which are difficult to manufacture and handle, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those circular regions are actually Fresnel reflectors consisting of thin concentric grooves whose faces are tilted as if formed from a parabolic mirror sliced into thin rings and "accordioned" down onto a surface.  They can be made holographically, diamond ruled, or made using a microlithographic process.